# How do I get 'matched' and 'unmatched' rows from a single table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I would like to have two stored procedures get the  'matched' and 'unmatched' rows, respectively... from a single table...

'matched' rows are two rows that have a state of 1 and 2 respectively, for the same:

```
uID aID cID and pID
```

An 'unmatched' row is a row that has a state of 1, but there isn't another row with a state of 2 that has the same uID, aID, cID and pID

( I have removed the unique identifier Indx from the data for brevity )

***Sample data***

```
uID aID cID pID state   occurs
10  200 5000    1240    1   2018-04-17 08:12:13.367
80  542 9000    5700    1   2018-04-17 08:12:54.113
10  240 5000    3860    1   2018-04-17 08:13:09.817
10  200 5000    1240    2   2018-04-17 08:13:18.010
30  240 7000    5938    1   2018-04-17 08:13:31.510
80  542 9000    5700    2   2018-04-17 08:14:04.363
```

Here are examples of 'matched' rows

```
uID aID cID pID state   occurs
10  200 5000    1240    1   2018-04-17 08:12:13.367
10  200 5000    1240    2   2018-04-17 08:13:18.010
80  542 9000    5700    1   2018-04-17 08:12:54.113
80  542 9000    5700    2   2018-04-17 08:14:04.363
```

Here are examples of 'unmatched' rows

```
uID aID cID pID state   occurs
10  240 5000    3860    1   2018-04-17 08:13:09.817
30  240 7000    5938    1   2018-04-17 08:13:31.510
```

**Matched Row code**

Where I am having difficulty is wrapping my head around the statement that group the matched sets... I thought I would be able to do something like this to get both rows with 1 and 2 but no such luck....

```
select uID, aID, cID, pID, state
from Data where state in (1,2) 
group by uID, aID, cID, pID, state
having state = 2 and state = 1
```

**Unmatched Row code**

Then I thought I would be able to do something similar for the unmatched rows, but this doesn't work either....

```
select uID, aID, cID, pID, state
from Data where state in (1,2) 
group by uID, aID, cID, pID, state
having state != 2 and state = 1
```

I need some *help*... thanks

***Infrastructure***

Here is the code to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Data](
    [INDX] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [uID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [aID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [cID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [pID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [state] [int] NOT NULL,
    [occurs] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Data] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [INDX] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

the stored procedure to "insert the data"

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertData]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

    @userID int, 
    @appID int, 
    @compID int, 
    @procID int, 
    @state int,
    @occurence datetime

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here

        declare @indx as uniqueidentifier
        set @indx = NEWID();

        insert into [Data]
        Values(
                @indx,
                @userID,
                @appID,
                @compID,
                @procID,
                @state,
                @occurence
                )

END
GO
```

and here is some code to help populate the table:

```
declare @userID int
declare @appID int
declare @compID int
declare @procID int
declare @state int
declare @occurence datetime

set @userID = 10
set @appID = 200
set @compID = 5000
set @procID = 1240
set @state = 1

set @occurence = GETDATE();
EXEC InsertData @userID, @appID, @compID, @procID, @state, @occurence
```

Test when adding another state:

```
    set @userID = 80
    set @appID = 546
    set @compID = 9000
    set @procID = 5700
    set @state = 3
    set @occurence = GETDATE();
    EXEC InsertData @userID, @appID, @compID, @procID, @state, @occurence
```

So I wind up with this data set:

```
uID aID cID pID state
10  200 5000    1240    2
10  200 5000    1240    1
10  240 5000    3860    1
80  542 9000    5700    1
30  240 7000    5938    1
80  546 9000    5700    3
80  542 9000    5700    2
```

So... scsimon... your query works great... but what if this were the case:

**NEW DUPLICATE DATA ADDED**

```
uID aID cID pID state
10  200 5000    1240    1
80  542 9000    5700    1
10  240 5000    3860    1
10  200 5000    1240    2
30  240 7000    5938    1
80  542 9000    5700    2
80  546 9000    4502    3
10  200 5000    1240    1
10  200 5000    1240    2
```

Query results, which is close...

```
uID aID cID pID state   occurs
10  200 5000    1240    1   2018-04-17 11:57:22.693
10  200 5000    1240    1   2018-04-17 11:57:29.797
10  200 5000    1240    2   2018-04-17 11:57:25.740
10  200 5000    1240    2   2018-04-17 11:57:30.827
80  542 9000    5700    1   2018-04-17 11:57:23.710
80  542 9000    5700    2   2018-04-17 11:57:27.767
```

But what I really want is this:

```
uID aID cID pID state   occurs
10  200 5000    1240    1   2018-04-17 11:57:22.693
10  200 5000    1240    2   2018-04-17 11:57:25.740

10  200 5000    1240    1   2018-04-17 11:57:29.797
10  200 5000    1240    2   2018-04-17 11:57:30.827

80  542 9000    5700    1   2018-04-17 11:57:23.710
80  542 9000    5700    2   2018-04-17 11:57:27.767
```

***Final Answer (thanks scsimon)***

'Matched'

```
select t.uID, t.aID, t.cID, t.pID, t.state, t.occurs
from Data t
inner join
    (select uID, aID, cID, pID
     from Data
     where state in (1,2) --optional if needed
     group by uID, aID, cID, pID
     having count(*) > 1) t2 on 
 t2.uID = t.uID
 and t2.aID = t.aID
 and t2.cID = t.cID
 and t2.pID = t.pID
 order by uID, occurs, state
```

Returns a set of :

```
uID aID cID pID state   occurs
10  200 5000    1240    1   2018-04-17 11:57:22.693
10  200 5000    1240    2   2018-04-17 11:57:25.740
10  200 5000    1240    1   2018-04-17 11:57:29.797
10  200 5000    1240    2   2018-04-17 11:57:30.827
80  542 9000    5700    1   2018-04-17 11:57:23.710
80  542 9000    5700    2   2018-04-17 11:57:27.767
```

'Unmatched'

```
select t.uID, t.aID, t.cID, t.pID, t.state, t.occurs
from Data t
inner join
    (select uID, aID, cID, pID
     from Data
     where state in (1,2) --optional if needed
     group by uID, aID, cID, pID
     having count(*) = 1) t2 on 
 t2.uID = t.uID
 and t2.aID = t.aID
 and t2.cID = t.cID
 and t2.pID = t.pID
 order by occurs
```

returns a set:

```
uID aID cID pID state   occurs
10  240 5000    3860    1   2018-04-17 11:57:24.727
30  240 7000    5938    1   2018-04-17 11:57:26.753
```

Comment: Think about your where predicate here. You asking for rows where state = 1 AND state = 2. A single row can't have more than 1 value so this will never return any rows. But since you have them grouped you could use count(*) = 2 to get both. And not sure what you are doing with <> 2 and = 1. That is just strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming each unique coupling of `uID, aID, cID, pID` will only be in these states once, you could use this.

```
--matching rows
select t.*
from table t
inner join
    (select uID, aID, ,cID, pID
     from table
     where state in (1,2) --optional if needed
     group by uID, aID, cID, pID
     having count(*) > 1) t2 on 
 t2.uID = t.uID
 and t2.aID = t.aID
 and t2.cID = t.cID
 and t2.pID = t.pID


 --unmatching rows
select t.*
from table t
inner join
    (select uID, aID, ,cID, pID
     from table
     where state in (1,2) --optional if needed
     group by uID, aID, cID, pID
     having count(*) = 1) t2 on 
 t2.uID = t.uID
 and t2.aID = t.aID
 and t2.cID = t.cID
 and t2.pID = t.pID
```

Comment: So... I chose to add another unrelated state... such as state = 3.... it still  works !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6167855/scsimon : how about if I have multiple records that are the same? ( see updated question )

Comment: I don't understand the follow on question. It seems like you just need to apply an `order by uID, aID, cID, pID, state, occurs` to the bottom of your query

Comment: check the state in the last duplicate data added sample... it goes 1,1,2,2,1,2  not 1,2,1,2,1,2

Comment: but if you add the order by I mentioned above, what happenes?

Comment: got it... needed to  order by uID, occurs, state -- SUPER query dude ... LOVE it !

Comment: no worries @user3174075 but you are starting to get into application layer logic, so you may run into some walls soon and need to handle this in your application, SSRS, etc. Cheers.

Comment: actually... these queries are the foundation queries for a "count"... so no 'row' data will be returned at all... only the counts... but they are exactly what is required, with respect to count of rows returned !

Answer (score 1):

I was able to replicate your expected output using `exists` and `not exists`

```
--Matched row code
SELECT * 
  FROM Data D1
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                 FROM Data D2
                WHERE D2.uID = D1.uID AND D2.aID = D1.aID AND D2.cID = D1.cID
                  AND D2.state = 2)
ORDER BY uID, state

--Unmatched row code    
SELECT * 
  FROM Data D1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                     FROM Data D2
                    WHERE D2.uID = D1.uID AND D2.aID = D1.aID AND D2.cID = D1.cID
                      AND D2.state = 2)
ORDER BY uID, state
```

Comment: So... I chose to add another unrelated state... such as state = 3.... it doesn't work.

Comment: The fact that there were more states than 1 and 2 wasn't made clear in the question.  You could attempt `D2.state IN (2,3)`.  Or `D2.state != 1`.  It might give what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

How about this. I'm assuming here there are only 2 states 1 and 2.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    Data a
  JOIN (SELECT uID, aID, cID, pID, Count(*) as NumMatches
        FROM   Data
        Group By uID, aID, cID, pID
        Having Count(*) = 2) b ON a.uID = b.uID and a.aID = b.aID and a.cID = b.cID and a.pID = b.pID
Order by a.uID, a.aID, a.cID, a.pID
```

and for non matches

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    Data a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT uID, aID, cID, pID, Count(*) as NumMatches
        FROM   Data
        Group By uID, aID, cID, pID
        Having Count(*) = 2) b ON a.uID = b.uID and a.aID = b.aID and a.cID = b.cID and a.pID = b.pID
WHERE IsNull(b.uID,0) = 0
Order by a.uID, a.aID, a.cID, a.pID
```

Comment: So... I chose to add another unrelated state... such as state = 3.... it doesn't work.